# Need Node js Query to remove the duplicates in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to the Mongodb database and JavaScript .I need to create the new column and that shoould be updated if the elements are matched or not .Need to remove the duplicates from the Mongodb records ( same policy contains other combinations) and the .I am getting below syntax errors , can anyone help me how to write the Node.js query to remove the duplicates .

Query :

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('Policy').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
counter = 0;
var records = db.getCollection('PolicySample').find().count();

db.getCollection('PolicySample').find().forEach(function(doc) { 
     var theQuery = { 
             'Transaction':doc.POL_ID
           }
           
      var theUpdate = {
               $set: {
                'Match':'Y';
               }
           };
      var arrayFilter = [
           {
               't.ObjectNr':doc.ObjectID,
               't.Status':doc.StatusOld,
               't.Interest':doc.Interest,
               't.Subline':doc.Subline,
               't.Code':doc.Code
           }
      ]
    bulk.find(theQuery).arrayFilters(arrayFilter).update(theUpdate);
});
```

Error :

he script cannot be executed as it contains the following errors:

Error at line 7, position 65: no viable alternative at input '('
Error at line 14, position 21: extraneous input ';' expecting {'[', '(', '}', ',', '=', '?', '.', '++', '--', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '>>', '<<', '>>>', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '==', '!=', '===', '!==', '&', '^', '|', '&&', '||', '*=', '/=', '%=', '+=', '-=', '<<=', '>>=', '>>>=', '&=', '^=', '|=', 'instanceof', 'in', TemplateStringLiteral}
Error at line 14, position 21: ;

Sample Data:

Comment: could you provide sample data ?

Comment: Sample Data   :POL_ID Object ID OLD Interest Subline Code NEW
11200 705 Auto OT 61 79 Comm
10732 709 Auto OT 000 0 Non
3138 708 RegularBI OT 61 0 Comm

Comment: please update your question and add sample data as json

Comment: Please find the JSON Data :{ 
    "_id" : {
        "POL_ID" : "6243", 
        "InsuredObjectID" : "USB", 
        "peril" : "Collision", 
        "InsuredInterest" : "MOT", 
        "subline" : "638", 
        "classcode" : "7942"
    }, 
    "Match" : "Y"
}